# we can achieve same thing with classes then why interfaces?

Tags: oop, interface

I know that interfaces cannot contain method body and we can implement in another classes and can write our custom logic. But the same thing can also implement by using inheritance with classes. Then why interfaces come into picture. If we want to override any method definition we can do in inheritance of classes and can write our custom code. What is the exact purpose of interfaces?

Answer (score 6):

One reason is that a class may implement multiple interfaces but only derive from a single class.

Another is, that hierarchically totally unrelated classes may implement the same interface. In statically typed languages without interfaces, one can often observe very deep inheritance hierarchies, created only because they could not simply implement an interface and had to force unrelated classes to derive. This often tends to violate the "Is a" - principle of inheritance. Such implementations also tend to drag around unused code, just because it is needed further down the inheritance tree.

tl;dr - it can be done but the results are often ugly and unmaintainable

Answer (score 2):

- Interfaces - The object can do this.
- Class - This is how the object does this.

Also interfaces can be used to avoid the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)